# SMS authentication for a website

Tags: authentication, mobile, sms

I'm looking to implement an SMS authentication for one of my projects, basically before a user is able to register an account with us, we would like to authenticate the user by sending sms containing a code to his mobile phone, and get him to put in the code in our form before he can proceed.

I've been looking around and found onVerify to be a pretty good way to go
http://www.onverify.com/

But I'd like to know if there're any other alternatives similar to onVerify as it is a bit expensive, so if I could go with cheaper one, that'd be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily enough if you have access to an SMS provider.

Typically you send an SMS to the user by making an HTTP request, containing the verification code. You'd store this code, and the recipient number, in some persistent database, against which you can compare when they fill in the details on the form.

You don't mention which geographic regions you expect your users to be in, which can be important given the variable delivery quality in some markets.

Have a look at the [HTTP API for BulkSMS](http://www.bulksms.co.uk/docs/eapi/submission/send_sms/), message [pricing](http://www.bulksms.co.uk/w/pricing.htm) and [coverage](http://www.bulksms.co.uk/coverage/).

Note that you can [register in various regions](http://www.bulksms.com/), if you, for example, want to price in USD.

Disclosure: I work at BulkSMS

Comment: Thanks, the management has decided the vendor to use, in any case I'll just accept your answer :)